# sql query without outer join key word

Tags: sql, outer-join

Is it possible to write a sql query where you know you have to use the left outer join..but cannot or are not allowed to use the "outer join" Key Word

I have two table sand want to get rows with null vaues from the left table ...this is pretty simple ...but am not supposed to use the key word....outer join....I need to right the logic for outer join myself

Comment: Why is this requirement? May be you should explain what you are trying to do first.

Comment: Are you trying to write the equivalent to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without using those SQL keywords?

Comment: If this is homework, please use homework tag.

Comment: If it's homework, add the homework tag. It attracts attention. Also, show us what you've already tried. you'll learn a lot from comments on your best efforts.

Comment: @Thomas ...Yes u got my question...thats exactly what I want

Comment: @abbas - SQL is a **relational database** system, which means it works by **`JOIN`ing tables together**.  Not being able to use `JOIN` means you may as well not be using a Relational Database.

Comment: @thomas...this is not homework...was aksed in an interview....

Comment: In that case, use the interview-question tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Field1 
FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)

SELECT Field1 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 where table2.id = table1.id)
```

This is something people do but it is deprecated and it does not currently work correctly (it sometimes will return a cross join instead of a left join)  so it should NOT be used. I'm telling this only so you avoid using this solution.

```
SELECT Field1 
FROM table1, table2 where table1.id *= table2.id
```

Comment: er, this is an anti semi join not an outer join!

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH t1(c,d) AS
(
SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'B'
),t2(c,e) AS
(
SELECT 1,'C' UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,'D' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'E'
)

SELECT t1.c, t1.d, t2.c, t2.e
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.c = t2.c
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.c, t1.d, NULL, NULL
FROM t1 
WHERE c NOT IN (SELECT c 
                FROM t2 
                WHERE c IS NOT NULL)
```

Returns

```
c           d    c           e
----------- ---- ----------- ----
1           A    1           C
1           A    1           D
2           B    NULL        NULL
```

(Equivalent to)

```
SELECT t1.c, t1.d, t2.c, t2.e
FROM   t1
       LEFT JOIN t2
         ON t1.c = t2.c
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you can just use `LEFT JOIN` - the `OUTER` is optional, just like `INTO` in an `INSERT` statement.

This is the same for all `OUTER JOIN`s.

For an `INNER JOIN` you can just specify `JOIN` with no qualifiers and it is interpreted as an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I know what ur trying to say...but I cannot use any join key words...Sorry for not explaining that

Comment: @Abbas - if you can't use any `JOIN` keywords then you may as well not use `SQL`.  Can you explain your situation?

Comment: @JNK This was an interview question...given that u cannot use any join keywords ...u have to write the Sql query for right outer join

Comment: @abbas - did they also ask you how to drive a car with no wheels?

Comment: @JNK I suspect this is ancient history to you, but the JOIN keyword was only standardized about ten years ago. Oracle could do outer joins with special operators before that, but MySQL didn't get them till version 4 and Postgres till version 7.1. Strangely, people still did work without them.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the rows in table A that don't have a matching row in table B:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM B
  WHERE A.id = B.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns all the matching rows from both tables:

```
    SELECT a.*,b.* FROM table_a a, table_b b
    WHERE a.key_field = b.key_field
```

Potential drawback is non-matches will be skipped.